# beamer slide number with footer

Tags: beamer, numbering, header-footer

I am using the warsaw theme and I need to have the footer with frame number the header of the code is:

```
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
%  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
}
```

If I uncomment the `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]` it would cause the footer to disappear. I am quoting the paragraph from [this site](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/02/beamer-and-latex-with-keynote-theme/):

> To get slide numbers in the footer
>   (next to the title of the
>   presentation) replace your \title{}
>   command with this:

```
 \title[Abbrev.Title\hspace{2em}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]{Full Title}
```

In this case, we must provide enough value to `\hspace` to align the slide number. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\hfill` to produce a stretchable space. Here I use makebox to get a fixed width, a bit shorter than half of the frame width, and `\hfill` to align at the right:

```
\title[{\makebox[.45\paperwidth]{Abbrev.Title\hfill%
       \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}]{Full Title}
```

I used the additional braces to protect the square brackets within the optional argument of `\title`.